# In Rails 4, how would you log and undo all database changes specific to one user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to set a specific user account as being "sandboxed", meaning I want to roll back any database changes that user makes when their session is destroyed.

I looked at using the Paper Trail gem, but I'm not sure it can be used to roll back changes specific to one user.

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean remove all their associated records? Or they're actually manipulating the schema?

Comment: Sounds like you just need a default for a sandboxed user and you just reset their db to that state when they log out.

Comment: @KevinBrown: The idea is that "sandbox user" may be making changes to records that already exist, and are not specific to that user. For example, let's say there is an `Article` object, created by another user, and "sandbox user" makes an update. I'd want that update to be rolled back, but not the whole `Article` record removed.

Comment: @DickieBoy: Here's the problem, though: if I define a save point at say 10am this morning, what if a *non* sandboxed user updates a record right after that? If I roll the entire DB back to the 10am state, I'll loose changes made by non-sandboxed users.

Comment: @GregMatthewCrossley, could you not use papertrail coupled with a `change_made_by_sandbox_user` bool and logic your way around rollbacks?

Comment: Meaning, papertrail allows custom strings, so you can bool your revisions (versions) as to if they're rollback-able. An after_destroy method will allow you to add any logic as to cleanup on user profile deletion.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have an activities table where you log all activities by user. Then, when a sandboxed user is deleted, you can go through the activities of that user, delete the corresponding entities.

```
bundle g model Activity user:references thing:references{polymorphic}:index
```

And when session is destroyed:

```
current_user_activities = Activity.where(user_id: current_user.id)
current_user_activities.each do |activity|
  activity.thing.destroy!
end

current_user_activities.destroy_all
```

Comment: When you say "delete the corresponding entities", do you mean actually destroying any records that they created? What about if the sandboxes user is just _updating_ an already existing record? I'd just want to roll back that update, not destroy the whole object.

Comment: In that case, add more columns to the activities table to track action (update, create, etc.) and action_details (perhaps json of old value and new value of  the affected fields), and use those to rollback the changes.

Comment: But this can get messy - a sandboxed user may make an update, another user may make a later update to the same thing - now what do you want? Should it rollback the original user's update, thus losing the newer user's changes, or should it leave it, because there were newer updates by other users?

Comment: So I guess what you're saying is that, as far as you know, there isn't a clean way to do this.

Comment: No, I am saying that sandboxing users means that all db writes should be only within sandboxed records - in other words, sandboxed users must not be updating existing non-sandboxed content.  If you allow sandboxed user activity to 'bleed' into non-sandboxed content, it is not even clear what it means to 'remove all changes created by that user' (see scenario in my last comment).